# grep fails to extract ip between SRC and DST using look behind

Tags: regex, grep, command-line-interface

My router is hammered (like everyone's) and I am curious as to country attribution (excluding obvious VPN contaminants).

I have a live log feed that I am piping through grep to extract the source IP address. From there I am going to pipe that to whois and gain country of origin through another grep.

The stream comes in via port 514, I am using nc, piped to grep using regex, but only getting IP address with a prefix of SRC. This line works:
`| grep --line-buffered -E -o "SRC=([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"`, but the output is `SRC=255.255.255.255`.

I tried regex `| grep --line-buffered -E -o "(?<=SRC=)(.*)(?= DST)"` for everything between `"SRC="` and `" DST="`. But grep produces nothing. As soon as I had a look behind, grep produces nil.

Here is an example from the feed (IP addresses obscured):`<4>Mar 13 08:19:09 kernel: DROP IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=255.255.255.255 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=238 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=34600 DPT=23 SEQ=282018820 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0`

I've tested regex online with `(?<=SRC=)(.*)(?= DST)` and it works there, but not on cli.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `-E` which does not support lookarounds, you can use `-P` to use a Perl-compatible regular expression if supported and make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far.

For example:

```
grep --line-buffered -oP "SRC=\K([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}(?= DST)" <<< "MAC= SRC=255.255.255.255 DST="
```

Output

```
255.255.255.255
```

Comment: worked only when I removed <<< "MAC= SRC=255.255.255.255 DST=" from CLI. Thanks.